# Load SVG image url and change image color

Tags: java, android, svg, android-imageview

I have url with SVG image, need to change image color in some cases. I had tried some way but not getting any success.

Could any one know how to change color of SVG image url in imageview?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SVG is in XML format, you can update the property of the specific object or location in your SVG through the path of that object.

Once you updated the SVG file through XML processing, you can then load the SVG to your image view.

Comment: But i am using https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/dst.svg thing kind of svg image url.

Comment: if you view the source of that link, you can see the SVG as XML, then you can do the processing.

Comment: I can see image but i want to change image color

Comment: that's why you need to update the SVG XML, to change the properties.

Comment: you can refer to this one, https://medium.com/@emmaguy/dynamically-changing-svg-colours-on-android-b026a99137ad

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `tint` to an imageview after loading `SVG` image into `ImageView`

```
imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.YOUR_COLOR), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

OR

```
imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.YOUR_COLOR), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: Thanks for help. but still not working.
Here is my code,
SvgLoader.pluck()
                .with(this)
                .setPlaceHolder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .load(url, image);

image.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);